# Google Apps, MX records and (some) lost email

Tags: g-suite, mx-record

I've been using Google Apps for a few domains for quite a while now (3 domains for 2 years or so) but recently suspected that I was 'losing' mail on one of the domains. After checking spam folders and the like I had a quick look on the mail host of my domain provider and found that it had been receiving some (but not all) email for quite some time.

The MX records on the domain are setup exactly as specified by Google and there are no other MX records present. The majority of email is making it to Google's mail servers but a minority somehow gets routed to the mail server at the hosting company.

I've independently checked the MX records with DNSStuff.com and everything looks correct.

I've got no idea where to look next. Any diagnostic tips?

One final thing: at my domain host there is an 'A' record for `mail.<mydomain>.com` that points to an IP address of a host at my hosting company. Is this at all relevant?

**Newsflash**

Repeatedly re-requesting the MX info from DNSStuff.com occasionally comes back with a single MX record pointing to the hosting company rather than the set of records pointing to google servers. How could this happen?

**Example of a 'bad' MX lookup**

```
DNS Lookup: mydomain.co.uk MX record
Searching for mydomain.co.uk MX record at a.root-servers.net [198.41.0.4]: Got referral to nsb.nic.uk. (zone: uk.) [took 42 ms]

Searching for mydomain.co.uk MX record at nsb.nic.uk. [156.154.101.3]: Got referral to ns10b.haisoft.net. (zone: mydomain.co.uk.) [took 26 ms]

Searching for mydomain.co.uk MX record at ns10b.haisoft.net. [109.169.14.200]: Reports mail.mydomain.co.uk. [took 122 ms]

Response:
Domain    Type    Class    TTL    Answer
mydomain.co.uk.    MX    IN    86400    mail.mydomain.co.uk. [Preference = 10]
mydomain.co.uk.    NS    IN    86400    ns10a.HAISOFT.NET.
mydomain.co.uk.    NS    IN    86400    ns10b.HAISOFT.NET.
mail.mydomain.co.uk.    A    IN    86400    178.170.127.30
ns10a.HAISOFT.NET.    A    IN    3600    178.170.127.30
ns10b.HAISOFT.NET.    A    IN    3600    109.169.14.200
```

**Example of a 'good' MX lookup**

```
DNS Lookup: mydomain.co.uk MX record
Searching for mydomain.co.uk MX record at e.root-servers.net [192.203.230.10]: Got referral to ns2.nic.uk. (zone: uk.) [took 60 ms]

Searching for mydomain.co.uk MX record at ns2.nic.uk. [217.79.164.131]: Got referral to ns10a.haisoft.net. (zone: mydomain.co.uk.) [took 102 ms]

Searching for mydomain.co.uk MX record at ns10a.haisoft.net. [178.170.127.30]: Reports ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM. [took 125 ms]

Response:
Domain    Type    Class    TTL    Answer
mydomain.co.uk.    MX    IN    86400    ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM. [Preference = 30]
mydomain.co.uk.    MX    IN    86400    ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM. [Preference = 30]
mydomain.co.uk.    MX    IN    86400    ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COM. [Preference = 30]
mydomain.co.uk.    MX    IN    86400    ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. [Preference = 10]
mydomain.co.uk.    MX    IN    86400    ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. [Preference = 20]
mydomain.co.uk.    MX    IN    86400    ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. [Preference = 20]
mydomain.co.uk.    MX    IN    86400    ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM. [Preference = 30]
mydomain.co.uk.    NS    IN    86400    ns2.mydomain.co.uk.
mydomain.co.uk.    NS    IN    86400    ns.mydomain.co.uk.
ns.mydomain.co.uk.    A    IN    86400    178.170.127.30
ns2.mydomain.co.uk.    A    IN    86400    80.93.82.202
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any other nameservers? They could be improperly configured/synced. Also you may check your DNS records at registrar.

Comment: Thanks. There are two nameservers listed for my domain (both belonging to the hosting company):
         ns10a.haisoft.net, 
         ns10b.haisoft.net

This info comes from the whois service at the registrar.

I'm not sure what this tells us. Perhaps I need to log a fault with the hosting company?

Comment: it does look like the two nameservers are serving up different data (ns10b.haisoft.net is stale). I've logged a fault with my hosting company.

Comment: the following very useful tool shows that there is a problem:

http://legacytools.dnsstuff.com/tools/traversal.ch?domain=mydomain.co.uk&type=MX

(obviously replacing mydomain with the domain in question)